# Python exec() not working when code gets compiled with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, base64, pyinstaller

I am trying to make a script that will decode some base64-encoded python script and then compile it with pyInstaller to make a .exe file.
My code looks like this:

```
import base64
exec(base64.b64decode(b"aW1wb3J0IHRpbWUKd2hpbGUgVHJ1ZToKICAgIHByaW50KCJIZWxsbyBUaGVyZSIpCiAgICB0aW1lLnNsZWVwKDEpCg==""))
```

when I ran the .py file, the code ran successfully, but when I compiled the code into a .exe file nothing happens. I looked into the task manager and my process wasn't even opened even after waiting for about 5 minutes.
I tried compiling the code with compile() as well but still no luck.
For anyone that is wondering that base64-encoded string says:

```
import time
while True:
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an older post, but I can answer the question for others who may find this.

What's going on here is that the bundled executable is missing the *time* library. According to PyInstaller's website:

> [Pyinstaller] analyzes your code to discover every other module and library your script needs in order to execute. Then it collects copies of all those files – including the active Python interpreter! – and puts them with your script in a single folder, or optionally in a single executable file.

...

> What other modules and libraries does your script need in order to run? (These are sometimes called its “dependencies”.)

> To find out, PyInstaller finds all the import statements in your script. It finds the imported modules and looks in them for import statements, and so on recursively, until it has a complete list of modules your script may use.

Because you included your import statement in the encoded string, PyInstaller wasn't able to find *time* as a dependency. Therefore the *time* library isn't in the environment that is executing your code.

To resolve the issue you can do 1 of 2 things:

1. The simpler way to fix the issue is to import *time* in your outer code where you import the *base64* library.
2. The tougher way would be to store the entire *time* library in an executable Python code object, convert that to base64, and include it with the rest of your inner code.